# Should I issue a toast when something is copied to clipboard?

Tags: web-app, dialog, copy-paste, toast

I'm working on a web-app with a button that copies some text to the users clipboard when clicked. I currently don't throw up a toast since I feel it would be excess noise (it's quite a simple copy operation). However, I have seen apps do this both ways - some issue a toast saying "Copied to clipboard" or something, while others do nothing.

Is there any real logic or pattern behind when a toast should be issued after copying to clipboard, or is it just arbitrary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, just show it above the text or copy icon, in some tooltip. This is how Font Awesome do it (check also github, they do the same):

[image: font awesome copied to clipboard tooltip]

Indeed as you said, the toast would be an overkill for such a small action. A tooltip or the checkmark icon would be enough.

If it comes to the logical part, it should be always communicated if something happens after user action, either by UI changes (checkmark) or text (copied!), so the user is ensured and they can move on.
Otherwise, if you don't communicate it, they can wonder about what is the icon doing or if it's even working.